# Calculate $\oint_\gamma \frac{1}{z(z^2+4)} dz$ over a circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

The task I'm given is to evaluate 
$\displaystyle \oint_\gamma \frac{1}{z(z^2+4)} dz$, where $\gamma$ is the circle with radius $1$ and center point $2i$.
I tried with Cauchy's Integral Theorem, but struggled so far.

Comment: What did you try with Cauchy Integral Theorem?

Comment: What is the radius of the circle of integration?  Also, I made a couple of minor edits to your post to clean up the $\LaTeX$

Comment: I split it up with partial fractions into 3 integrals and then 2 of them become 0 because $\gamma$ is a closed circle, but I don't get a solution for the third one

Comment: Sry kinda messed up the notation

Comment: The direction of $\gamma$ matters, but we'll assume that it's counter-clockwise because that's the standard orientation.

Comment: You "*struggled* so far"? How?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**
$$\frac{1}{z(z^2+4)}=\frac{\frac{1}{z(z+2i)}}{z-2i}$$

Set $g(z)=\frac{1}{z(z+2i)}$ in Cauchy Integral Formula.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Calculate the locations of the poles.  This is where the denominator of the integrand vanishes.  Since 
$$
\frac{1}{z(z^2+4)}=\frac{1}{z}\cdot\frac{1}{z-2i}\cdot\frac{1}{z+2i},
$$
we see that $0,\pm 2i$ are the poles.

**Step 2:** Determine which locations of the poles are within the circle $\gamma$, in this case, $0$ is of distance $2$, $-2i$ is of distance $4$, so only $2i$ is within the circle.

**Step 3:** Calculate the residues, at $z=2i$, see this function is $$
\frac{1}{z-2i}\left(\frac{1}{z}\cdot\frac{1}{z+2i}\right)$$
We see that $z-2i$ vanishes to order $1$ at $z=2i$ and the rest is holomorphic near $z=2i$, so we can just plug in to get the residue.  In particular, the residue is
$$
\frac{1}{2i}\cdot\frac{1}{2i+2i}=-\frac{1}{8}.
$$

**Step 4:** Apply Cauchy's integral formula to get that the integral is $2\pi i\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)=\frac{-\pi i}{4}$.